# Possible mcrypt spelling error?

Tags: php5

While attempting to start a project with Laravel, the following warning is produced multiple times:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/mcryot.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212/mcryot.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

I'm wondering if the error is because the searched-for file is **mcryot.so** instead of **mcrypt.so**. Anyone have experience with this or know where I might begin looking?

Comment: [It's never a surprise to find something as lame and careless as a spelling error in anything to do with PHP.](http://eev.ee/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/). (Sorry, couldn't help myself.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Placing a symbolic link to `/usr/lib/php5/20121212/mcrypt.so` named `mcryot.so` in `/usr/lib/php5/20121212/` should do:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/php5/20121212/mcrypt.so /usr/lib/php5/20121212/mcryot.so
```

Comment: Or just use a binary editor (`bvi` works fine) to locate `mcryot.so` in the `php` binary and fix the name.

Comment: Thanks, @kos! That did the trick. I ended up having to comment out mcrypt from my php.ini file too since it looks like it was already loaded into the PHP binary. (I don't 100% understand the implications of that, but it's enough to get the errors to stop)